# React-navigation, tintColor is missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, react-navigation, eslint-config-airbnb

I have put my react-navigation code into a separate Routes file which I am then importing into my App.js file. Everything is working fine but I am using Airbnb ESLint config in Atom/Nuclide and getting an error with tintColor...

**"tintColor is missing in props validation"**

Tried this:

Routes.propTypes = { tintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,}

**But then get error "tintColor PropType is defined but prop is never used"**

This is part of the code

```
const Routes = () = {
const ContentNavigator = TabNavigator(
{
  Profile: { screen: ProfileStack },
  History: { screen: HistoryStack },
  Questions: {
    screen: QuestionsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="question-circle" type="font-awesome" size={20} color=
 {tintColor} />
      ),
    },
  },
  Notifications: { screen: NotificationsStack },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Profile',
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: COLOR_PRIMARY,
  },
  backBehavior: 'none',
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an additional [Functional Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components), add [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for it and use in your main component. For example:

```
...
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...

const QuestionsTabBarIcon = ({ tintColor }) => (
  <Icon name="question-circle" type="font-awesome" size={20} color={tintColor} />
);
QuestionsTabBarIcon.propTypes = {
  tintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

...

const ContentNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: { screen: ProfileStack },
    History: { screen: HistoryStack },
    Questions: {
      screen: QuestionsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: QuestionsTabBarIcon
      },
    },
    Notifications: { screen: NotificationsStack },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: COLOR_PRIMARY,
    },
    backBehavior: 'none',
  }
);

...
```

Comment: Will try this.   Thanks for the answer

Comment: What if you need to use a different Icon "name" property for each icon? Instead of question-circle for example.. How would you make QuestionsTabBarIcon reusable?