# is missing in props validation React JS

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I created the component:

```
const elementaryInfo = ({
  postTitle,
  imageUrl,
  facts,
  factSummary,
      }) => {
  return (<div> ....
```

And i have this error:

```
postTitle, imageUrl, facts, factSummary is missing in props validation
```

I found [this quetsion on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033208/missing-in-props-validation) but it contains solution for components created like a class.
Also i found [this question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396202/react-navigation-tintcolor-is-missing-in-props-validation) and added code below:

```
elementaryInfo.PropTypes = {
postTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
imageUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
facts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
factSummary: PropTypes.string.isRequired
```

but it didn't solve my problem, i've got the different error :

```
Unreacheble code detected. Typo in static class property declaration.
```

Please help me how can i solve it?

Comment: There is a typo in propTypes. It should be `elementaryInfo.propTypes = {
postTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
imageUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
facts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
factSummary: PropTypes.string.isRequired};` and where did you got the unreachable code error?

Comment: Unreachable code usually means that you either return early or syntax error like missing brackets, colons, commas, etc. Check your code for that. With that new code you have introduced some kind of a syntax error most likely. Sounds like this job could have been solved with Typescript

Comment: your component name ` elementaryInfo` should begin with capital letter

Comment: @Vishnu yeah, thank you, i solved it, unreachable code error i 've got when i added propTypes after return

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin thank you for your comment you helped me, now i know more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Matz it simply should be `elementaryInfo.propTypes`for the declaration.